# Twilio Conversations - Random Screen Blanks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, twilio

We are working on a video conference App. During conversations, chrome screen randomly blanks out(Have attached a screenshot).

When the screen has blanked out, following chrome functionalities does not work:

1. Right click does not work.
2. Developer Console cannot be opened through Keyboard Shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + C), but can be opened through File -> More Tools -> Developer Tools.
3. On opening Developer Tools, we get the message

> DevTools was disconnected from the page. Once page is reloaded, DevTools will automatically reconnect

4. Page cannot be refreshed by Ctrl + R/F5, but clicking the Address Bar and hitting Enter refreshes the page.

Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)

Twilio Conversations Version - 0.13.7

The issue can be replicated with the quickstart-js guide - https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-javascript

Steps to Replicate:

1. Clone the Quickstart Repo into 3 different folders i.e. have 3 separate folders with quickstart.html & quickstart.js files.
2. Navigate to https://www.twilio.com/console/video/dev-tools/testing-tools after login and create 3 separate access tokens.
3. Set the 3 access tokens in the 3 different quickstart.js files.
4. Start all 3 servers. (You might have to edit the start_server.sh file to edit the port numbers since all 3 will try to serve on port 8000. Or you can start your own server with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the parent directory of the 3 folders and access the html file through `localhost:8000/folder1/quickstart.html`
5. Open up all three quickstart.html files in browser in separate tabs.
6. Invite every participant in all three browser tabs. So, User1 invites User2 & User 3, User2 Invites User1 & User 3 and so on..
7. After a few minutes, chrome blanks out.

[image: Blanked out Screen]

Any idea on why this happens and how to debug the issue?

Comment: Are you able to try with another browser?

Comment: I am not able to replicate the issue with Firefox (Version 47.0). The video freezes but the page does not blank out.